# How to extract the matched pattern using re module

Tags: python

While I execute the below program with little modification I am getting an error.

```
import sys,re
match=re.compile(r'aa[0-9]+AB')
while 1 :
    line=eval(raw_input('Enter the string to search' 'or' "press 'q' to Quit"))
    if line == 'q':
        print "you are quit from the program"
        break
    if  match.search(line):
        print 'Matched:',line
        print pat
        print 'found',match.group()
        print type(pat)
    else:
        print "no match"
        print type(pat)
```

Input:

```
'aa12AB'
```

O/P:

```
>>>  Matched: aa12AB
<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x02793720>
found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Pyth`enter code here`on27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 325, in RunScript
    exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
  File "C:\Users\thangaraj\Desktop\python program\UK Training program\New to add labtop\regular exp\Script1.py", line 11, in <module>
    print 'found',match.group()
AttributeError: '_sre.SRE_Pattern' object has no attribute 'group'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign to a `match` object:

```
m = match.search(line)
```

and then:

```
m.group()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `eval`? You should use `match.search` (although you should probably rename the variable from `match` as usually, the return value of `search` is called a match) and the return value of `search` will have a `group` method, as @Birei wrote.